# Golang проверка MX-записей через файл txt

Tags: файлы, golang, dns

Есть файл большой mail.txt он содержит 1млн строк мне нужно отделять домены и проверять на MX-Записи доменов
Выглядит он вот так:

```
s.ingall@gazetaweb.com
```

А мне нужно, отрезать почту и выводить массив строк, например вот так

```
gazetaweb.com
```

у меня есть вот такой код, который проверяет мх-записи

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "log"
    "ioutil"

)

func ReadFileDomains() {
    file, err := os.Open("mail.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        if err = file.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    fmt.Print(b)
}

func CheckEmail() {
    domains := ReadFileDomains()
    txtrecords, _ := net.LookupTXT(domains())

    for _, txt := range txtrecords {
        fmt.Println(txt)
    }
}
```

Суть в том, что мне нужно быстро чекать домены и передать метод чтения файла доменов в net.LookupTXT(ReadFileDomains) и записать результат файла

Comment: а в чем конкретно проблема? что ожидаете? что не получается?

Comment: я не понимаю как массив из файла mail.txt перенси в net.LookTXT(domains()) чтобы он чекал большое количество

Comment: А нам не понятно как вам помочь так как нет сути, конкретики. Что значит "перенести"? Что значит "чекал большое количество"? Чем конкретнее вы сформулируете ваш вопрос, тем больше шансов получить ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в LookupTXT нужно передавать вам домен в виде строки. а для этого вам нужно сначала получить эти данные из файла. читайте, проверяйте, передаете в net.LookupTXT строку

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net/mail"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func ReadFileLines() []string {
    lines, err := readLines("mail.txt")
    if err != nil {
        return []string{}
    }

    return lines
}

func CheckEmail() {
    for _, txt := range ReadFileLines() {
        _, err := mail.ParseAddress(txt)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("invalid address: %s\n ", txt)
            continue
        }

        if ok, domain := check(txt); ok {
            fmt.Printf("tada: %s\n", domain)
        }
    }
}

func check(email string) (bool, string){
    at := strings.LastIndex(email, "@")
    if at >= 0 {
        username, domain := email[:at], email[at+1:]
        fmt.Printf("Username: %s, Domain: %s\n", username, domain)
        return true, domain
    }

    return false, ""
}

func readLines(path string) ([]string, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    var lines []string
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        lines = append(lines, scanner.Text())
    }
    return lines, scanner.Err()
}


func main() {
    CheckEmail()
}
```

файл mail.txt

```
s.ingall@gazetaweb.com
s.ingall@gazeb.com
s.ingall@google)
```

выхлоп:

```
Username: s.ingall, Domain: gazetaweb.com
tada: gazetaweb.com
Username: s.ingall, Domain: gazeb.com
tada: gazeb.com
invalid address: s.ingall@google)
```